# Why use terminal to start jar and idea to start are inconsistent

Tags: intellij-14

Using idea to start the springboot program cannot get the value of the automatic configuration class

For example, the following code,PassConfig.getKey() is null:

```
private static final String encryptionFormat = String.format("to_base64(aes_encrypt(?,'%s'))", PassConfig.getKey());
```

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mybatis.key")
public class PassConfig {

    private static String key;

    public static String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        PassConfig.key = key;
    }
}
```

At present, it can be solved by org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value  annotations.

```
@Value("${mybatiskey}")
public void setKey(String key) {
    PassConfig.key = key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **PassConfig** you specified the **prefix** to be "mybatis.key" and the String as **key**

According to this, in **application.properties** your property is expected to be **mybatis.key.key** (prefix.variablename)

in setKey you specified the @Value to take **mybatiskey** from **application.properties**

property names should be consistent. It is null because most probably you don't have the propery **mybatis.key.key** in your **application.properties** file.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a sucker.

This configuration was wrong when I copied it to the stackoverflow, actually prefix = "mybatis"